# How to overcome error 0x800F0A12 while installing Win 7 SP1?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, service-pack

I am trying to install Win 7 SP1 (using Windows Update), but it failed with 0x800F0A12. I have a dual boot configuration windows - linux, otherwise perfectly normal configuration.

This web page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1-sp1-installation-error-0x800F0A12
suggest some fixes, but only the first one seems relevant. However I get:

```
C:\Users\ga>mountvol /E
Access is denied.
```

The main reason why I am so keen to have it installed is because Windows stopped recognizing my optical drive (it just completely vanished after one of the automatic updates). It might be related to this issue.

An ideas how to fix it?

EDIT:
Following @vcsjones' advice I managed to run `mountvol /E` successfully, but it didn't help with the SP1 installation unfortunately.

Comment: In your command prompt, is it elevated? (It will say "Administrator" in the title bar). If not, run it elevated by typing "cmd" in the start menu search, and holding "ctrl+shift" whild clicking it. Then try your mountvol.

Comment: @vcsjones: thanks, it did fix the access denied issue. Trying the update again...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by going to disk manager and setting the windows C: disk as active. On my setup, that didn't cause any problems with GRUB and everything worked fine.

Comment: Didn't really help :(

Comment: @Grzenio  Can you post what your partitions looks like? There are lots of tips on the various blogs and forums about this, but I'm not sure which are applicable in your case. Do you have the small "windows system" partition?

Comment: what exactly would you like to know? (ideally let me know which cmd line tool to run :)

Comment: @Grzenio  which are your active partitions and on which partitions is /boot and windows C:.

Comment: @Grzenio or better post a screenshot of your partition map

Answer (score 0):

I have been also getting the 800F0A12 error when I was installing Windows 7 Service Pack 1. That is what I finally did.

1. [Restored](https://askubuntu.com/a/5767/323249) Windows 7 master boot record (MBR) with the `install-mbr` command. As a result, I was able to boot straight to Windows 7 bypassing the GRUB menu.
2. [Extracted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460616/73766) `BootRec.exe` from a [recovery partition](https://superuser.com/questions/296919/where-can-i-download-bootrec-exe#comment2016704_985374) and executed `BootRec.exe /FixMbr`.
3. Marked Windows 7 system disk as active in the disk management tool (see @AndrejaKo's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/249910/283168)).

I am not sure which of these steps are crucial, but I was able to successfully update only after I completed the last step above.

(Then, I fixed MBR to enable GRUB back.)

FYI. Originally, my Lenovo ThinkPad X201i laptop had Windows 7 only preinstalled. I repartitioned it in order to install Linux. This is how my disk looks like now:

[image: Windows/Linux dual boot partitioning]

- `/dev/sda1` - a small system partition that came with the laptop
- `/dev/sda2` - a Window 7 system partition
- `/dev/sda4` - a Linux partition; long time ago, it was a part of `/dev/sda2`
- `/dev/sda3` - a recovery partition that came with the laptop