# Where can I download "bootrec.exe"?

Tags: windows-7, boot, iso-image

I have my Windows 7 x64 ISO on my pendrive, but WinToFlash app forgot to install the MBR (again).

The only PC I have, uses x86 Win7 , so it won't install the *bootrec.exe*, since that is a 64bit binary.

I need the /boot/ folder from the Win7 ISO/disc. (32-bit)
Where can I download only that? Can anyone give me a link?

Comment: Found a "bootsect.exe" on ZippyShare using Google, and it works. HOWEVER, this is not really safe (even if Avast says so), so the question remains open.

Comment: I doubt you'd be able to download folder folders such as those.. without having to resort to "seedy" places. Perhaps I can upload it somewhere.

Comment: I'd appreciate that upload. But seriously... Microsoft doesn't provide a _legal_ way for people? :/

Comment: you can borrow a Windows DVD or download a Windows DVD over torrents and use your key and remain legal.

Comment: @Sathya - I'm using MSDN ISO. But this happened to me a lot of times. Downloaded the ISO from my MSDNAA account. Made the (there are some options here) USB install "disk", and then it wouldn't boot. Now, you don't have a PC where you can fix things ... worse if you have a PC with XP and so on. Downloading the whole ISO again (since you used YOUR PC to do that), takes some time.

Comment: @Shiki This is happening 'lots of times'? You need something better than WinToFlash. Take a look at Rufus. Free, open source, and it's never failed me yet. http://rufus.akeo.ie. *I'm not affiliated with Rufus at all, I just use it and it work well.*

Answer (score 21):

BootRec.exe is not officially available for download. However, you can extract it from any legitimate Windows 7 ISO.

You'll need something capable of reading a WIM file - [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) should suffice for this. From the root of the ISO, open `.\sources\boot.wim`. From there, BootRec.exe can be found in `.\1\Windows\System32\`.

Comment: If this is true I believe it should be marked as the best answer.

Comment: On my old Lenovo ThinkPad X201i, it can be found here: Hidden recovery partition → `7z l FactoryRecovery/sdrivebackup.wim | grep -i '\.wim'` → `Recovery/WindowsRE/winRE.wim` → `7z l winRE.wim | grep -i bootrec.exe` → `Windows/System32/BootRec.exe`.

Answer (score 5):

you can find it in the install.wim\Windows\System32\Recovery\Winre.wim\Windows\System32\bootrec.exe

Comment: Man that was the only working and real adress to that file, yet this post has 2 dislikes. What the .. is wrong people?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft doesn't offer individual files from their operating systems available for download. However, you can legally and safely download the entire Windows 7 64-bit .iso from http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65805/X15-65805.iso

Sources: This SuperUser [answer](https://superuser.com/a/305434/213131), which provides a full list of ISOs available for download, as well as *that* answer's [original source](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/).

***Or*** you could visit a friend and make a copy of the file from their computer...

Comment: Are you sure that `bootrec.exe` is inside ISO? I have have browsed original Windows7 ISO content and found no `bootrec.exe`. There is only `boot\bootsect.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a working computer that has a similar image, such as in an enterprise environment, you can do the following: <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then type `recdisc.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will give you the dialog used to create a repair disc which when finished contains a `WinRE`-image that has `BootRec.exe` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hiren's Boot CD contains several boot environments that include that tool, among others (Try Mini Windows XP).  You can download it here:

Download:
http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/

Info:
http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

Comment: Thanks for the hint for [Hiren's Boot CD 15.2](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/old-versions/). After booting from that ISO, its "Dos Programs" menu contains lots of MBR tools (and there is a trick: type "M" + "<ENTER>" in DOS command line will bring up Hiren's Boot CD's menu, to save you from a reboot to switch to next tool). I'm yet to find a bootrec.exe nor any tool to be able to fix my hard disk booting issue, though, but still thanks for sharing the interesting Hiren's Boot CD.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install grub on the drive using a linux distro which will automatically scan and add all available operating systems on the drive to it's loader.
Note removing the usb drive woun't affect booting.

More info 1 [Recovering GRUB after installing Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7)
More info 2 [Grub as bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

Answer (score 1):

You can open up boot.wim using the free 7-Zip utility at http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply download the entire .Iso installer file of the windows OS you are using and look for it in the folders or simply do a search in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can still boot into Windows, then this should work on Windows 10:

- From the windows start menu, or in the cortana search box enter ‘Change advanced Startup Options’
- Alternatively go to 'Settings' from the windows start menu, and search 'Recovery options'.
- Under 'Advanced Starup' click 'Restart now'.

When the computer restarts, choose 'Troubleshoot', 'Advanced options', and select 'Command Prompt'.

When the computer restarts, you should get a recovery prompt where 'bootrec.exe' is available. You may have to login with your windows account first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To be fair, I mostly used the tool for recovery, where you can't boot anymore. But, the issue is getting less and less relevant now. 1) I was able to backup the tool for all Windows for myself. Which every IT admin should do I guess until Microsoft comes to it's senses. 2) Today we have 100mbps+ connections, SSD, etc. Back in '11, it was a major hassle to grab an entire ISO, extract, and just copy up the tool. Thank you for your post!

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract BootRec.exe from the Windows 10 ISO file.
My Win 10 is in 7z archive, so I used the 7-Zip program to browse the Wim in the ISO.

If you have just a plain ISO, which is not compressed in any other format you can still browse the ISO with 7-Zip.

The file location is as follows:

```
\Microsoft_Windows_10_x64.iso.7z\Microsoft_Windows_10_x64.iso\sources\boot.wim\2\Windows\System32\BootRec.exe
```

I right clicked on the file and extracted to desktop, so I can copy to my System32 folder.