# Repairing Windows 7 boot loader after installing Windows XP on another drive/partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bootloader

I've had Windows 7 installed for a while now and decided to install XP on another drive. It appears that XP has overwritten 7's boot loader, so XP boots up by default. I popped in my Windows 7 install disc to repair the loader. After selecting the repair option, it shows me this:

[image]

I clicked Repair and Restart and it *still* boots into XP by default. Luckily, I can go into my BIOS and do a manual override to get it to boot from the Windows Boot Manager on the drive that 7 is installed on. My goal is to have Windows 7/XP dual boot, but, for now, I just want to get the Windows 7 loader working properly.

And I am aware that there are several nearly- identical questions on here (I anxiously await the onslaught of "possible duplicate" comments and close votes), but they're all about 10 years old except for one where the answer is a link to a 20-minute YouTube video. None of them address my issue anyway.

**Edit:** As expected (and predicted in the paragraph preceding this one), it was closed as a dupe. I've seen all those questions/answers and I do not have an option to open a command prompt. I am literally only able to select Repair and Restart.

Also, when I remove the drive that has XP installed on it from the boot priority in BIOS and attempt to use my Windows 7 disc, I get this:

[image]

Comment: @Moab, I state in my question that I inserted my Windows 7 disc and only had the option to Repair and Restart. I didn't have a command prompt option.

Comment: Did you press Shift-F10 while booted into repair mode? Also, specifically, which Windows 7 install disk are you using?

Comment: @music2myear No luck on the SHIFT+F10 (I pressed it at every screen in spite of there being no prompt for that option). I am using my Windows 7 x64 install disc. However, I've figured it out and will be posting the solution as answer here in a few

Answer (score 1):

Many answers I've found point to using bootrec.exe to rebuild the MBR or boot loader. However, as mentioned in my OP, booting with the Windows 7 install disc did *not* give me any option to open a command prompt. In searching for the physical location of bootrec.exe on my local drive or install disc, I came upon this question:

[Where can I download "bootrec.exe"?](https://superuser.com/questions/296919/where-can-i-download-bootrec-exe)

It turns out that it's actually wrapped up in a .wim file on the disc in `.\sources\boot.wim` which can be opened with 7zip as an archive. Within that, bootrec.exe is found in `.\1\Windows\System32\`. So, while booted into Windows 7 using the aforementioned BIOS override, I extracted bootrec.exe to my desktop, opened an elevated command prompt, and ran the below commands:

[image]

I initially ran `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, but wasn't confident it worked when it said it couldn't find any Windows installations. I then tried `bootrec /fixmbr`. Still uncertain if it worked, I rebooted my machine and, lo and behold, Windows 7 booted up just as it used to.

So now we can add yet another solution to the problem introduced by installing Windows XP on another drive/partition after installing Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to boot into Windows 7, you can do this with a tool named "SuperGrubDisk". In Windows 7, simply open a command prompt and run "bootrec /rebuild".